# Forced layout using rectangles instead of circles

Tags: d3.js

I would like to implement this D3 force layout example;

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658

But I don't want to use circles, I want to use squares.

I've tried to construct a collision function, but it only works if I disable gravity. Which is not what I want.

```
this.collide = function collide(quadtree, node, alpha) {

    var that = this, d = node, doSnap = false;

    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

        var q = quad.point,
            val,
            dif,
            inX,
            inY,
            wy,
            hx,
            a,
            b;

        val = 100 * (Math.pow(e.alpha, 2));;

        // Don't compare an element to itself,
        // don't modify fixed elements
        if (!q || q == d || d.fixed) {
            return;
        }

        // Calculate bounding coordinates
        a = that.getCoordinates(d, d.width, d.height);
        b = that.getCoordinates(q, q.width, q.height);

        // If they don't overlap at all, do nothing
        if (!that.doesOverlap(a, b)) {
            return;
        }

        // Calculate Minkowski sum
        wy = (a.width + b.width) * (a.cy - b.cy);
        hx = (a.height + b.height) * (a.cx - b.cx);

        if (wy > hx) {
            if (wy > -hx) {
                // Collision on the top
                a.point.y += val;
            } else {
                // Collision on the left
                a.point.x -= val;
            }
        } else {
            if (wy > -hx) {
                // Collision on the right
                a.point.x += val;
            } else {
                // Collision on the bottom
                a.point.y -= val;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Forces in the force layout are calculated based on treating the nodes as points and specifying a target distance between them, so repulsive forces between square objects won't account for corners if you treat each square as a node.

You can, however, treat each square as a collection of nodes connected with links. Nodes could be placed at all corners of the square and at the center. Since nodes can have their target distances based on a function, you can make the center nodes effectively 'larger' than the corner nodes. This would give you a layout approximating squares without having to compute the forces.